# Finder not enabling use of Services when changing "Service receives selected" input

Tags: macos, finder, automator

I have a Service on automator that applies to Files and Folders in Finder. Initially it was saved as "Text" input.

Problem is, Finder won't show this Service to Files and Folders. If I go to settings, it's still placed under the "text" categories.

Comment: This works for me ([1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uZAam.png), [2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hCMZ3.png)). What do you mean by "Finder doesn't enable it"?

Comment: I created this as a new > service. But finder doesn't show it on the Service menu. If I go to settings, it's placed under the "text" categories. Also, even if I assign a shortcut, finder won't fire it against selected files and folders.

Comment: I've had problems with services possibly related to caching before. I solved those by *File » Duplicate* and entering a different name. Make sure to get it right the first time you save the new service.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OS X sometimes ignores changes to services after they've been saved in Automator, possibly due to caching. So if the service started out as a *text* service, chances are your changes aren't getting picked up. To circumvent this problem, select *File » Duplicate* in Automator and save the service under a new name, and try again. Then delete the original service from `~/Library/Services`.

Comment: Thanks. It got me out of trouble with a service I was creating.

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to Daniel's answer, you may also consider restarting your computer. This should clear the cache if that's what really is causing the problem. Since this is definitely a bug, there is no absolute path. What worked for me after restarting was opening the service workflow in Automator, creating and saving the duplicate, wait, and finally see both the services on the menu. Next, I just deleted the duplicate service and it disappeared from the menu after a while.